# Scroll function doesnt work after using some elements

Tags: javascript, scroll

Im using a scroll function this works perfect whenever I use normal text for it, but whenever I use `Text<br>Text<p>` it wont scroll automaticly because there is a`<p> or <br>` what to do to make it also scroll for once with other elements.

And is there a simple way to use it for all `$('#scrollDiv')` istead of copy paste it above every line?
Example usage:

```
//This scrolls correct
$('#scrollDiv').append('Hello world!');
scrollDiv($('.scroll-text:eq(0)'));

//This wont work scrolling
$('#scrollDiv').append('Hello<br>world!');
scrollDiv($('.scroll-text:eq(0)'));

//This also wont work
$('#scrollDiv').append('<span style="font-size:100px;">Hello</span>');
scrollDiv($('.scroll-text:eq(0)'));



function scrollDiv($div, h){
    var scrollHeight = $div[0].scrollHeight;
    var scrollTop = $div[0].scrollTop;
    var height = $div[0].clientHeight;
    var h_invisible = scrollHeight - scrollTop - height;

    if(h){
        if(h>h_invisible){
            $div.scrollTop(1e5);
        }
    }else{
        if(15>h_invisible){
            $div.scrollTop(1e5);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
scrollDiv($('.scroll-text:eq(0)'), 50);
```

could help you out..